# reCAPTCHA image verification improvements

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Sometimes when I'm quick, I get a reCAPTCHA to verify that I am human. I'm totally fine with this. Today I got a reCAPTCHA with images. I had to select peanuts or street signs, and somehow I am not able to get past that reCAPTCHA. Either it is not working, or I am dumb enough but that really sucks. I had to beat reCAPTCHA by pressing the back button, wait a bit and resubmit my post.

Can reCAPTCHA be changed so that it doesn't test if I'm super-human, but just human? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my answer [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/10769/498587).

Once you pass the reCAPTCHA once, you *shouldn't* get it again for a while.

Honestly if you're not paying complete attention it **is** actually easy to miss a correct image in the selections.

Best bet is to make sure you do it correctly once or twice and you should be good from then out (on that device).

If you for some reason can't pass, **clear your browsing data & cookies** then try again. Maybe something was bugged.

---

Also, just want to point out there's no way *to my knowledge* to 'disable' this feature of reCAPTCHA. I set one up on my own site and **the settings are pretty basic**:

[image]

Comment: yea, you shouldn't get it again once it is known that a human exists, but i do WAY to often.  Here and in most places, even google, acting like a Robot and repeating things over and over like all the other mindless humans makes you human?  but being different , wildly different and uniquely human , makes you a robot :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not just you, the captcha is bugged and often unsolvable. Especially the street signs one. There's a lot of complaints in the google groups.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/recaptcha/hdReseEjcYk/eHj6yAsNCAAJ
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/JukqkEd-0vo